# Openssl pick certificate from certificate bundle in C (.pem format)

Tags: c, openssl, certificate

I have a certificate chain in PEM format and I need to retrieve in C each one of the certificates from the bundle. The file looks as follows:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

I've seen how to do it using .p12 files but I need to do it using a .pem formatted file now. This is how I do it using .p12 files

```
FILE *p12_file;
PKCS12 *p12_cert = NULL;
EVP_PKEY *pkey;
X509 *x509_cert;
STACK_OF(X509) *additional_certs = NULL;

p12_file = fopen("/etc/certs/chain.p12", "rb");

d2i_PKCS12_fp(p12_file, &p12_cert);
fclose(p12_file);
int result = PKCS12_parse(p12_cert, "password", &pkey, &x509_cert, &additional_certs);

unsigned char * certificate;
int len_certificate = i2d_X509(x509_cert,&certificate);

 X509* x509_subCA2 = sk_X509_value(additional_certs,0);
unsigned char * subCA2;
int len_subCA2 = i2d_X509(x509_subCA2,&subCA2);

 X509* x509subCA1 = sk_X509_value(additional_certs,0);
unsigned char * sUbCA1;
int len_subCA1 = i2d_X509(x509_subCA1,&sUbCA1);
```

I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code so far?

Comment: There you have it